# Huge amount of close_wait after .NET CORE webapp recycled on IIS behing Windows NLB

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, iis, nlb

Trying to find out the root cause of this issue for weeks without success, hope someone will get new ideas where to look.

We have an Inprocess .NET Core application running on Windows 2012RC2 with IIS Ver 8.5 (.net core hosting 2.2.6).
This application is duplicated on 2 servers sharing the same IP through Windows NLB. 
Both machines are physical with recent HW and 1GB link

The traffic managed by the application is IMHO not that high at all (300 requests per minute !!)

However, randomly when IIS the application pool is recycling, the application is not able to send the `ACK` from the TCP sequence to acknowledge the `CLOSE_WAIT`. Ending up with **exponential number of close_wait connection** [close wait comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFABZ.png)  (see traffic picture of the 2 servers at issue time)

The server at one point is not able to serve anything anymore.
This will end-up either with the default keepalivetimeout of windows occurs or if we manually recycle again the apppool.

Looking into `tcpview` tool at that time, the close wait are linked to the system process , so not able to know if it is the new *worker process* or the *closing one* which triggered this issue.

What I don't understand is why suddenly the app can't ACK the new close_wait calls ?

- Because of the "VIP" (NLB) shared by the servers ? For us configuration and HB traffic seems ok.
- Something wrong with IIS and .net core Inprocess model ? Didn't see anyone complaining about that
- Any httpclient definition in the code wrongly done ? devs had a look ad didn't find anything wrong there too
- Is the application is not able to send the `ACK`  or not able to detect the `FIN_ACK2` ?quite hard to see when the close wait increase so quickly, even with wireshark dump on big server

Mitigation was to reduce Windows keepalived time and controlling the recycling at very low traffic time, but I would like to know if anyone has any other idea where to dig into, or had same issue...

Comment: please check the value for TCP KeepAliveTime. By default, this is set to two hours (120). the best practice is to set the value lower and if you are using a session in your web app then set the same as your session value. To set the value to 20 minutes, use the hex dword value 0x00124F80: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters] "KeepAliveTime"=dword:00124F80`

Comment: Thanks but for the reply but this change has been already done ( snapshot of close_wait in the picture does not show this change). Keepalive time is now at 5mn .  We 're trying to solve the root cause of the close_wait .

Comment: could you please share what kind of app pool recycling? Scheduled recycle? Manually recycle? Unexpected recycle(eg, crash)?if possible share more details regarding the observed “CLOSE_WAIT” connections? (Like Local Address, Foreign Address, Process ID). what kind of connections it is Incoming connection or Outcoming connection?

Comment: in my opinion, the issue is more likely a system related issue that happens on the kernel mode layer. If possible, try to set up a new server by deploying the same application and see if the issue can be reproduced? or create a “HelloWorld” website with a new Application pool on the impacted server to see if the issue can be reproduced. If the issue persists, it should have nothing to do with ASP.NET Core.